# Redhat 7.5 rhel ibm x3850 x5 2 node

Tags: linux, cpu, ibm, redhat, rhel

У меня проблема с установкой и запуском redhat7.5 на ibm x3850 x5 node 1 and node 2: при загрузке ядра - сервер перезагружается и никаких ошибок, никаких предупреждений в журнале. Иногда система загружается правильно, я не понимаю почему.

Система включается чаще, если в конфиге grub написать `men = 1024M nr_cpus = 2`.

VMware исправна, Ubuntu работает правильно, а CentOS и redhat - нет... пожалуйста, помогите мне :)

Comment: We can't understand you problem, 'cos here russian community, and much users doesn't  know English